# Can`t Load multiple select with different data in cascade select in z-song laravel-admin

Tags: laravel, laravel-admin

Laravel Version: 8.74.0
Laravel-admin: 1.8.14

I use cascade select but I can't load multiple select with different data at the same time

## More explanation

I would like to use multi-select:
A => B
A => C
A => D
"Select A options" is a static list
"Select B options" depends on "Select A Value"
"Select C options" depends on "Select A Value"
"Select D options" depends on "Select A Value"
How is it possible?

```
$form->select('modele_id', __('Modéle'))->options($modeles)->load(
    ['version_id', '/admin/api/versions'],
    ['options', '/admin/api/options'],
    ['accessoires', '/admin/api/accessoires']
)->required();
$form->select('version_id', __('Version'))->required();
$form->listbox('options', __('Options'));
$form->listbox('accessoires', __('Accessoires'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution

```
$form->select('modele_id', __('Modéle'))->options($modeles)->loads(['version_id', 'options', 'accessoires'],['/admin/api/versions', '/admin/api/options', '/admin/api/accessoires'])->required();
$form->select('version_id', __('Version'))->required();
$form->listbox('options', __('Options'));
$form->listbox('accessoires', __('Accessoires'));
```